# Error working with Yeoman Generator

Tags: reactjs, npm, yeoman

I am following the tutorial here : http://yeoman.io/codelab/index.html

At step 5, I run `npm run serve` and get the following error on the build:

> ERROR in ./src/app/components/TodoTextInput.js
>
> /Users/pro/Documents/Code/React/Yo/Tutorial/mytodo/src/app/components/TodoTextInput.js
>   40:13  error  Unnecessarily quoted property 'edit' found  quote-props
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/` it is blank. I will appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with the Fountain webapp generator. (see [their github issues](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=quote-props))

The error message goes away when you remove the quotes from the edit property at 
`TodoTextInput.js:38-42`.

Before:

```
    className={
      classnames({
        'edit': this.props.editing,
        'new-todo': this.props.newTodo
      })}
```

After:

```
    className={
      classnames({
        edit: this.props.editing,
        'new-todo': this.props.newTodo
      })}
```

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp/issues/182#issuecomment-284171505).